# Start splash screen after application termination

Tags: java, android

in my project I have static member as `User.current`. 
If I run the app after it terminates in background, `User.current` will be null. I get user from server on splash screen.
I want to start splash screen when I run terminated application.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: you can save user data in shared preference  and get data from shared preference  when you want in application.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a server, you probably use an Async task. In Async task

```
...
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
     ...
     value = jsonObj.getString("value");
     return true;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean iHaveValue) {
    if(iHaveValue){
       // use case 1 or 2
       // 1
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("value", value);
       startActivity(i);

       // 2
       SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
       editor.putString("value", value);
       editor.commit();

       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

You get the user on the doInBackground(Void... params). And in the onPostExecute(Boolean iHaveValue) method you simply go to the MainActivity.
You can use the intent to put the value and receive on MainActivity (1) or use a shared preference (2)

(1)

in SplashScreen

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("value", value);
startActivity(i);
```

in MainActivity

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splashscreen.class);
```

(2)

in SplashScreen

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("value", value);
editor.commit();
```

in MainActivity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
value = prefs.getString("value", "null");
```

If you need use this value for multiple locations, sharedPreferences helps a lot (case 2). If not, use putExtra to send info to MainActivity (case 1).

Comment: I would like to suggest using `PowerPreference` instead of the old implementation of shared preference `PowerPreference.name("user").put(key,value)`